# Reference request: localisation of categories

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, derived-functors

I'm trying to track down a result mentioned in Verdier's *Categories Derivees* appearing in SGA 4.5. In chapter 2, 3.1 (page 280 in SGA 4.5) Verdier mentions that categorical localisations always exist, and cites [C.G.G] for this result. The problem is, [C.G.G] does not appear anywhere else in SGA 4.5 (in particular, it is not in the bibliography). Does anyone have any idea what paper / book Verdier is referring to here?

Comment: The canonical reference is the classic book of Gabriel and Zisman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a guess.

From the bibliography of Schiffmann Gérard's Théorie élémentaire des catégories (1962) which can be found on page 33 of Séminaire Banach (1972):

[image: Chevalley, Gabriel et Grotendieck - " Catégories et foncteurs " - A paraître]

(It may be hard to find or lost as [Chevalley had a habit of only keeping a single copy of his papers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IWogUgYoZI&t=15m10s).)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately, it seems as though this unpublished book is totally lost.

Comment: I ran into this thread when searching the exact same reference. One might notice that there might be an implicit reference to this book in SGA1 VI 1 as a footnote (page 146) : "Les auteurs définitifs sont C. Chevalley et P. Gabriel. Le livre doit sortir en l'an 2000. Cf. aussi SGA4 VI 7.1." SGA1 being redacted in the sixties (if I'm not mistaking), there is some chance that it is intended as sarcasm about a potential release of this book...

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you are looking for, but if you only need the fact of existence of localizations, then in his [lectures](https://perso.math.univ-toulouse.fr/btoen/files/2012/04/swisk.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506201149/https://perso.math.univ-toulouse.fr/btoen/files/2012/04/swisk.pdf)) Bertrand Toen shows (see page 3) that localizations of categories exist. Though, for the main part of his proof Toen cites the [book](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/BOOKS/EKMM.pdf) by Elmendorf, Kriz, Mandell, May ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20220606091711/http://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/BOOKS/EKMM.pdf)).

Comment: At the moment, I'm not so much interested in finding *some* source for the existence of localizations as I am in finding the *specific* source that Verdier is referring to.